# ISP login, MAC spoofing, WiFi and multiple devices

Tags: isp, mac-address, headless, spoofing, wimax

I have a Tikona Digital Broadband (WiMax based) Internet Connection which allows limited number of devices to be connected at a time and also requires that the users login with username and password (by visiting a browser page on each device) before beginning to browse Internet.

If more than the allowed number of devices are to be used, some of the previous devices must be removed from their portal. They track these devices using MAC addresses.

Physically they have a wireless device at the roof of my building which has a CAT5 cable running to a powered device in my room. Another CAT5 cable from this powered device will connect to my Laptop or wireless router.

I have a *Beetel 450TC1* ADSL + Wireless router from my previous connection which I am currently using in Bridge mode to be able to browse wirelessly. Router's DHCP is also disabled and my devices get IPs assigned by the ISP's devices directly.

**I have these problems/questions:**

1) Each device needs to enter a username and password using a browser which limits some of the devices like backup devices, personal cloud device, media servers, download boxes etc from being able to connect to Internet as they don't have a browser.

2) Since these devices get IP from the ISP I am not able to access them from my laptop as its not a static ip and no way of finding out what was assigned to these headless devices.

3) How can I have my current router (or a new one) to be able to login to the ISP's page automatically on powering, maintain a local IP pool for my devices and laptop which can then access Internet through my router spoofing the MAC addresses ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out that the Beetel 450TC1 being an ADSL+ Modem and Wireless Router does not play well with the onboard 4 port ethernet switch.

There is no clearly marked WAN port for the ethernet switch and the software assumes the WAN to be always through ADSL. As a result, the router never acquires an IP from the ISPs DHCP.

Bridge mode obviously will let you connect two ethernet connections and that is the only way it will work with this device.

I also tried upgrading the firmware but the problem was still the same so its safe to assume that this router doesn't support ethernet based WAN connections.

I tried same settings with an very old wired router (DLink DL604) which had no problems in maintaining a local network while being connected to the ISPs DHCP on the other end.

Answer (score 1):

First, I think you will need to disable bridge mode and turn on DHCP.  The problem then becomes how to authenticate the router through a web page.  Try connecting a PC on the router, if you are lucky you can bring up the web page from there.

Otherwise, I think you'd need a Linux system with two ethernet ports, directly connected to the incoming CAT5.  You could use a webpage on it and also set up the routing.  Then you use connect the Beetel to your Linux system.  Obviously a lot more configuration!  I don't see an easy way of logging in to the webpage.

Comment: I could do a curl post on startup of my headless device as it runs debian and is hackable. Problem really is with how the Internet functions. No IP is assigned to my router if I put it in DHCP mode (maybe because its not a normal router but an ADSL+ Modem / Router combo) by the ISP.